# pd.read_sql_query string list parameter collapsed to first element

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I'm encountering an odd problem with `pandas.read_sql_query()` method where when I pass a parameter that is a list formatted as a string, the parameter only reads the first element of the list and drops everything else. The original list is a list of numbers that is re-formatted as a string, so in theory, all elements of the list should be preserved. For example, the dataframe returned by this code:

```
    l = [1, 2, 3]
    l_as_str =  ", ".join([x for x in map(str, l)])
    
    QUERY = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in (%(l_as_str)s)"""
    
    df = pd.read_sql_query(QUERY, params={"l_as_str": l_as_str}, con=engine)
```

...only consists of items where id = 1, the first element of `l`. If I switch the order of elements (e.g. `l = [2, 1, 3]`), then it only returns items where id = 2. In other words, the `l_as_str` appears to get collapsed to just the first element. Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Just simplify with an f-string.  No need to pass `params`

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l_as_str =  ", ".join([x for x in map(str, l)])
    
QUERY = f"""SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in ({l_as_str})"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(QUERY, con=engine)
```